# python scrapy response statis

Tags: python, scrapy

```
def all_type(self, response):
    if response.url is 'http://www.ccdy.cn/zhuanti/' and response.url is 'http://www.ccdy.cn/difang/':
        if response.status != 404:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.all_article)
            for i in range(0, 24):
                type_url = response.url + 'index_' + str(i) + '.htm'
                yield scrapy.Request(url=type_url, callback=self.all_type)
```

Why have I disabled the status code to 404 and no longer access it, but the crawler still accesses the 404 page? This is a crawler written by `scrapy`. The main problem is `response.status != 404` does not work.

Comment: Can you print "response.status" just before the print statement and provide the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is never going to do anything, because the first **if** conditional:

```
if response.url is 'http://www.ccdy.cn/zhuanti/' and response.url is 'http://www.ccdy.cn/difang/':
```

will always be False, and so it will never go inside the **if** code block.  Maybe you want an OR there instead of an AND?

...or maybe your indentation is wrong, or at least coming to me wrong.  In any case, the **if** makes no sense because it is obviously always going to be False.